# Is it possible to enable 'Development Mode' in live org?

Tags: visualforce

I have enabled 'Development mode' in a dev org fine as per -

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=pages_dev_mode.htm&type=5

In my dev org this gives a very handy footer on visual force pages where you can explore running variables etc.

However having enabled it in my live org I dont get the footer on my VF pages :-(

I cant find any docs as to if it is dev org only?

Any ideas or experience here?

Thansk

Comment: why its so.You will get it.  Go to the Setup | Administer | Manage Users | Users| select for which user you want to enable the developer mode,Please refresh the page once. how you are creating vf pages ?

Comment: Hi as mentioned I have followed the same steps for my dev and live org as detailed in the link.  The visual force page is actually hosted on a sites page and is publicly available on the web if that might make a difference?

Comment: Yes, it's possible to activate dev mode, but in a production org you can't edit any visualforce page, apex class, trigger, etc...

Comment: @Alberto - Thankyou.  Can you confirm if I should still be able to see the footer (but just not make edits?) as mentioned I have 100% enabled it in my live org logged out and back in but its still not showing...

Comment: It's not showing in my org... I'm pretty sure it's not showing in production. All the development and tests should be done in a sandbox first, so there wouldn't be any reason of seeing the dev panel in production.

Comment: @Alberto - thanks for you help.  You can actually edit vf pages in prod but yes fully agree understand all dev should be done in sandbox then pushed live.  HOWEVER .... sadly I have some code that works in SB but not live so haveing that footer in live would be good for some de-bugging...but never mind - cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to activate `Development mode` in a production org, but you won't see the bottom panel because you can't alter metadata (visualforce pages, apex classes, triggers, etc) in an active org. I've just tested it on an enterprise edition.

The only way to alter metadata is from a connected sandbox via `change sets`.

[image]